# 2 estilos de fuente a la vez con swing

Tags: java, java-swing

Necesito una manita, estoy con `swing` y para aplicar a un texto una fuente solo puedo meter los parámetros clásicos :

```
Font despues= new Font(estilo,Font.ITALIC,tamaño);
```

El caso es que necesito usar 2 estilos de fuente a la vez, concretamente italic y bold.

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes crear una combinación de ambas usando `|` para usar Italic y Bold:

```
Font myFont =  new Font(estilo,  Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC ,tamano);
```

o puedes usar también `+`

```
   Font myFont =  new Font(estilo,  Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC ,tamano);
```

Comment: +1 para usted, Excelente!

Comment: Muchas gracias! @J.Rodríguez